# zf2 application doesn't enter view file

Tags: zend-framework2

i have a strange problem in my zf2 application and I cannot handle it.
I've got my module colled Auth. In this module I've got controller AuthController and a action loginAction().
To make it easier let say that the action is empty. There is only `return array()` part.
And now in my module.config.php i've got

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions' => true,
    'doctype' => 'HTML5',
    'encode' => 'UTF-8',
    'not_found_template' => 'error/404',
    'exception_template' => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'error/404' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'auth' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

for layout everything works fine(I see all what it contains). But application doesn't enter the view file (view/auth/auth/login). 
Moreover if i delete view/auth/auth/login file application still displays layout and no error. It's looks like it doesn't want to read any view...
Any guess?

Ahhh I forgot to add that i put `die` on this action and this die displays correctly

Comment: If you have found your solution, please post an answer to the question so other users can tell that it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess your layout file is missing the line to echo the inner view model content:

```
<?=$this->content?>
```

For a full example, take a look at the layout file from the skeleton application: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml